# Inject variables into all twig templates from parameters.yml

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.8

I am using Symfony 2.8 and I am trying to inject a variable into all Twig templates as docs says [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html) so I made this changes at `app/config/config.yml`:

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        admin_skin: "%admin_skin%"
```

and `app/config/parameters.yml`:

```
admin_skin: skin-blue-light
```

But I end with this error:

> You have requested a non-existent parameter "admin_skin".

This is what logs says:

```
in ParameterBag.php line 94
at ParameterBag->get('admin_skin') in ParameterBag.php line 214
at ParameterBag->resolveString('%admin_skin%', array('admin_skin' => true)) in ParameterBag.php line 185
at ParameterBag->resolveValue('%admin_skin%', array()) in ParameterBag.php line 175
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array('admin_skin' => '%admin_skin%'), array()) in ParameterBag.php line 175
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array('debug' => '%kernel.debug%', 'strict_variables' => '%kernel.debug%', 'globals' => array('admin_skin' => '%admin_skin%')), array()) in ParameterBag.php line 175
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array(array('form' => array('resources' => array('AvanzuAdminThemeBundle:layout:form-theme.html.twig')), 'globals' => array('admin_theme' => '@avanzu_admin_theme.theme_manager')), array('debug' => '%kernel.debug%', 'strict_variables' => '%kernel.debug%', 'globals' => array('admin_skin' => '%admin_skin%')))) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 45
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 107
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 589
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in Kernel.php line 511
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in Kernel.php line 133
at Kernel->boot() in Kernel.php line 182
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 30
```

This is changed in Symfony 2.8 and I am not aware? Did I miss something here? Where is my error?

If I set the value directly in `app/config/config.yml` as follow it works:

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        admin_skin: skin-blue-light
```

Comment: It seems the parameter file is not imported in the right configuration file, maybe because you have different params/config files to load for different environments?

Comment: @gp_sflover lol, you and other maybe will kill me since the problem is simple: I didn't upload right `parameters.yml` properly and for that reason the key wasn't found, I have uploaded right and it works, anyway thx for your time

Comment: Often the solution to a problem is already stated in the error message :-)